# radeditor contenteditable anchor tags not selected in ie11

Tags: internet-explorer, attributes, contenteditable, versions

Am using radeditor. User will be inserting links (anchor tags) into it. And the anchor tags will have contenteditable="false" just so the link text is not changeable. But, the problem is when I click on the link the entire link text is supposed to show as selected.

[image: First Image]

This is working fine on IE7 and in compatibility mode with higher version browsers. 
But, in standard mode of IE 8, 9, 10 and 11 it does not.

[image: Second Image]

This gives an impression that its purely related to browser engine. But, I would like to know if there is any alternative approach for this issue to show the links as selected.

Appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't bring the same appearance like the first screenshot. But, I was able to select the element as a whole using some custom script which is fine for the end user in my case. Below is the script if some is looking for.

```
function OnClientLoad(editor, args) {
    editor.attachEventHandler("onmouseup", function (e) {
        var selectedElm = e.srcElement;
        if (selectedElm.tagName && selectedElm.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
            editor.selectElement(selectedElm);
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
}
```